# from asp table to array

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have created a table in my client's web page using asp:

```
<asp:Table ID="Table1"  GridLines="Both" 
    HorizontalAlign="Center" 
    BorderWidth="2"
    Font-Bold="True"
    Font-Names="Verdana" 
    Font-Size="8pt" 
    CellPadding="15" 
    CellSpacing="0" runat="server">
 </asp:Table>
```

Using a button I have created, I fill the table using an array:

```
for (int j=0; j < cells; j++)
{          
    TableRow r = new TableRow();
    for (int i = 0; i < row+1; i++)
    {
        TableCell c = new TableCell();
        c.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl (datar[j,i].ToString()));
        r.Cells.Add(c);
    }
    Table1.Rows.Add(r);
}
```

This code works fine to fill the table. Now I have to create another button to send the table to Excel. Does anyone know how to do that, or how to read the data from the table and send back to another array?

the user has to decide if he wants to save the data from the table to excel, this is why a create the second botton "Save info", button one is for display info

Comment: If you have the data in an array already, why do you need to pull it back out of the table?  Just use your array `datar` to build Excel or CSV output file.

Comment: the array i mention is the "datar" which is located in button1, now how can i use parse the array from button 1 to button 2? the user has to decide if he wants to save the data from the table to excel, this is why a create the second botton "Save info", button one is for display info

Comment: If you need to read the information back, you could try to put this into a foreach(Row r in table.rows) { foreach (string data in r) { list.add(data); } } and then convert the list to an array. This is more psuedo code... I am refering to how I pull stuff out of a database since the concept should be the same. Scout around for the right syntax

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I cant vouch 100% for this because I don't have an actual table filled with information to test it on, but try this out anyways.

```
    Table t = new Table();

    List<string> cells = new List<string>();
    foreach (TableRow r in t.Rows)
    {
        foreach (TableCell cell in r.Cells)
        {
            cells.Add(cell.ToString());
        }
    }

    String[] array = cells.ToArray();
```

This assumes we don't have to define a fixed array before starting to put stuff into it, so to avoid this I simply created an array and converted the list into one. Thats programmatically slow. To get the array size before hand, just multiply String[TableWidth * TableHeight] and you will have a fixed array of the correct size.

Comment: wont work when you declare table t =new table(); you are creating a new table, not using the table that is been show on the web page

Comment: As I have pointed out, I don't have a real table to work with. I gave you a table as a demonstration. Replace the t variable with your own table and see if it works.